# Can the Japanese version of Soul Calibur V change menu language?

Tags: ps3, soul-calibur-5

I live in Taiwan, and apparently there's no Chinese version of the game here. The PS3 version mentions something about switching language, but my Japanese is really poor - especially reading. I'm not sure if you can switch the menu language or just the subtitles or voice acting. If you can switch the menu language to either Chinese (traditional) or English, I'd be able to play it. Is that possible, or should I just buy it in English online?